# Store Regex via Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can i store regex via Mongoose schema to then be queried by mongoose as regex?

```
//regexmodel.js 
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var RegexSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 regex: {
  type: REGEXP //How do i get this to store regex
 }
})

var Regex = mongoose.model('Regex', RegexSchema)

module.exports = Regex

//regexController.js
var regex= new Regex({
  regex: /.*/
})

regex.save(function(err, alert) {
 if (err) {
  res.send({success: false, message: err.message})
 } else {
  res.send({success: true, message: "Created Regex"})
 }
})
```

Keep in mind that it is all psudo code and not anything i am actually trying but goal of this will be to be able to have that value match to ANYTHING. I need this done on the DB and not the query side as i know you can query mongoose with regex to match but it doesnt fit my use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you question is more of a theoretical nature the answer is **yes** you can do that.

Options you have:

1. You can implement that type yourself since mongoose [supports custom types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html).
2. You can simply use one of the already developed plugins which have already done the work for you. For example https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-regexp. 
   I am sure if you search `gitHub` you might find more than one of
   these.